# php foreach repeating twice

Tags: php, foreach, zend-lucene

I have been trying different solutions for this problem without success. Problem is this:

I have some results form Zend_Search_Lucene which give say 3 results with the ID of: 2, 3, 4

Then I have some records from an unrelated Query made with Doctrine which gives me say two records with the id ID: 2 and 3.

The results from Search Lucene should show on the page as total of 3 records. Of these I need to check if an ID is equal to another ID of the Docrine query, that is if there is a match ie: 2=2 , 3=3 show something, if not ie: 2=3 show another thing.

Trying to do this with FOREACH twice and an IF ELSE sttement but I get double results on the page:

```
foreach($this->results as $r):    //  records form search Lucene ie 2, 3, 4

    foreach($this->records2 as $r2){     // records from another table (query) 2 and 3

          if(($r2['id']) == ($r->id)) { 
                                      // do something

                            } else {
                              // dosothing else

    }
```

...etc.

I understand why the records are repeated twice but I dont' know what is the right way to get the right result. Can someone please help?
My apology if there is some silly thing I am doing. :)

Comment: I'm missing some } at the end of your code, do you have those in your real code and why is the first foreach loop with a : and not with { and at the end a }?

Comment: Can you explain me what would be the right result ?

Comment: Sorry I just tried to show the problem the code works fine wiht all teh }.

Comment: The right result is: 2=2. 3=3, 4<> either 2 or 3. So the first two show something and the thir one something else. But there must be only 3 results on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(... $r) {
  $found = false;
  foreach(... $r2) {
    if (... == ...) {
      $found = true; break;
    }
  }
  if ($found) {
    // something
  } else {
    // something else
  }
}
```

Comment: why does the else if have a <? if the id's do not match it should always do the other thing (thats what i read atleast).

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread the question. I thought you were getting symmetrical repeats... Will fix now.

Comment: I have tied with an elseif but still got the proble of repeating twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the inner `foreach` if the array in `$this->records2` is a map like this:

```
array(2 => array('id' => 2));
```

Then inside the first foreach:

```
if (isset($this->records2[$r->id])) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

In this way, `// do something else` and `// do something` are executed at most one time per loop.

Comment: if and else have similar content with few changes to mark the difference

Comment: I just couldn't make your work straight away. But I will give it a second try as it looks cleaner. Thank you.